# Extract token from JSP tag using java

Tags: java, regex, spring

I have String s as input  which is shown below and I want to extract tokens i.e title ,cssErrorClass , id, maxlength ,name along with right hand side value  .
What can be the best approach to extract tokens using java.

```
     String s = <s:textfield title="Total" cssErrorClass="err1" id="id_0" maxlength="6" 
      name="intTotal" ></s:textfield>
```

I want output to be like this shown in example:

```
Example: 
title =Total 
maxlength=6
name= intTotal etc.
help me out to build the logic for same.
```

Comment: Do you have the JSP snippet always one by one tag like in the example, or only in a bigger set of input? Is it important to also select the actual tag? If not, how did you achieve that? (Asking, because maybe there is a way that you could just extend the extraction of a single tag to also get its attributes.)

Comment: How about using an XML parser?

Answer (score 1):

Using the DOM:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            String s = "<s:textfield title=\"Total\" cssErrorClass=\"err1\" id=\"id_0\" maxlength=\"6\" \n" +
"      name=\"intTotal\" ></s:textfield>";
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
                    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            try (InputStream stream
                    = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(UTF_8))) {
                Document doc = builder.parse(stream);
                Element elm = doc.getDocumentElement();
                String[] attrs = {"title","cssErrorClass","id","maxlength","name"};
                for (String attr: attrs) {
                    System.out.println(attr + "=" + elm.getAttribute(attr));
                }
            }
        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
title=Total
cssErrorClass=err1
id=id_0
maxlength=6
name=intTotal
```

Comment: can you share code along with import statement ??

Comment: @PrashantMishra import statements added